# STM32F411E-DISCO Uart circular buffer on interrupts

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, uart, stm32f4discovery

I would like to receive and transmit data that will be put into a circular buffer. I have functions for inserting characters and reading characters.

How can I use these functions and where should I put them? Currently I transmit and receive what I send to the terminal and it works fine.

I am just learning, please give me some advice

```
#define UART_RX_BUF_SIZE 7
#define UART_TX_BUF_SIZE 7

int8_t uart_put_char(char data);
int8_t uart_get_char(char *data);

volatile char uart_rxBuff[UART_RX_BUF_SIZE];
volatile char uart_txBuff[UART_TX_BUF_SIZE];

void uart_put_string(char *s);

typedef struct {
  volatile char *const buffer;
  uint8_t head;
  uint8_t tail;
} circ_buffer_t;

volatile circ_buffer_t uart_rx_circBuff = {uart_rxBuff, 0, 0};
volatile circ_buffer_t uart_tx_circBuff = {uart_txBuff, 0, 0};

uint8_t received_char;

int8_t uart_put_char(char data) {

  uint8_t head_temp = uart_tx_circBuff.head + 1;

  if (head_temp == UART_TX_BUF_SIZE)
    head_temp = 0;

  if (head_temp == uart_tx_circBuff.tail)
    return 0;

  uart_tx_circBuff.buffer[head_temp] = data;
  uart_tx_circBuff.head = head_temp;

  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_TXE);

  return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
int8_t uart_get_char(char *data) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  if (uart_rx_circBuff.head == uart_rx_circBuff.tail)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  uart_rx_circBuff.tail++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  if (uart_rx_circBuff.tail == UART_RX_BUF_SIZE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    uart_rx_circBuff.tail = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  *data = uart_rx_circBuff.buffer[uart_rx_circBuff.tail];                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  if (huart->Instance == USART1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    // uart_put_char(&received_char);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &received_char, 1, 100);                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // uart_get_char(received_char);
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &received_char, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't use the stm32, but do similar things on the TI msp432. Generally, the card should supply both a read and transmit buffer (though you can certainly provide your own). When reading or writing from UART, there will be an interrupt set when the receive buffer receives a character. You can use the interrupt function to handle both the transmit and receive. You must ensure you subsystem clock is running fast enough to simultaneously transmit and receive. I have had problems in low-power mode with a 3MHz clock at 115,200 baud on the TI card, but a 12MHz clock seems to have no problems.

Answer (score 4):

I want to put a side-note first, so it doesn't get missed:
I would suggest incrementing your head and tail indices *after* you've put the byte in the buffer. So, upon initialisation, head is `0`. When you call `put_tx`, the byte will be stored at index `0` and *then* be incremented to `1`. When the interrupt calls `get_tx`, the tail is still `0` so you'll get that first character, *then* it'll be incremented to `1`. Doesn't really matter, but I think it's easier to write clean code if you think in this way.
Also, it's totally a micro-optimisation, but think about setting your buffer size to a power of 2. That way, instead of going `if (head==BUF_SIZE) head=0;` you can go `head &= BUF_SIZE-1;` and you'll save a few clock cycles, no need for a test. ;-)

---

It definitely is a pain to set up, but very much worth it if you can get around the multiple steps. The HAL will probably handle much of this for you, but I don't know enough about that.

1. You need an interrupt handler for UART events.
2. You need to tell the UART to raise interrupts for `RXNE` (receive not empty), and `TXE` (transmit empty) when you've sent a character.
3. You need to tell the NVIC to enable the UART interrupt.
4. I definitely recommend having push and pop (or put and get) functions for both buffers. The interrupts will call `put_rx` and `get_tx`, while user code will call `put_tx` and `get_rx`. Or better yet, write some wrapper functions, like `Uart_Send(char)`, `Uart_SendBuffer(const char*, size_t)`, `Uart_TryReceive(char*, size_t)` that will call `put_tx` and `get_rx`.

If the HAL is as smart as I think it is, you can can probably combine steps 1-3 into a single step, and just implement `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` (as you've done) and `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback`.

I don't know how the HAL works enough to give you an exact solution (all my STM32 work is built on headers I made myself before I realised even CMSIS existed - whoops!) so here's how I would do it in low-level code.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler() __attribute__((interrupt))
{
    // This would probably be handled in HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback
    if (USART1->SR.RXNE)           // We've received a byte!
        uart_push_rx(USART1->DR);  // Push the received byte onto the back
                                   // of the RX buffer.

    // This would probably be handled in HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback
    if (USART1->SR.TXE) // Transmit buffer is empty - send next byte
    {
        char nextByte;
        if (uart_pop_tx(&nextByte)) // Get the next byte in the buffer and
            USART1->DR = nextByte;  // shove it in the UART data register.
        else                       // No more data in the circular buffer,
            USART1->CR1.TXEIE = 0; // so disable the TXE interrupt or we'll
                                   // end up stuck in a loop.
    }

    if (USART1->SR.TC) // There's also a flag for 'transmit complete'. This
    { } // is different from TXE in that TXE means "Okay, I've started this
        // one, tell me what'll come next," whereas TC says "Okay, I've
        // finished sending everything now. Anything else, boss?"
        // We won't use it, but be aware of the terminology. The HAL might
        // try and confuse you with its words.
}

void InitialiseUart()
{
    HAL_UART_Configure(&huart1, baud, stopBits, andStuff, probably, etc);
    HAL_UART_Enable(&huart1);

    // You probably don't need to worry about anything below here,
    // if the HAL is smart. But I've included it for completeness,
    // so you can understand more of what the MCU is doing.

    // Enable RXNE (receive not empty) interrupt
    USART1->CR1.RXNEIE = 1;
    // Don't enable TXE (transmit empty) interrupt yet. Only when you send 
    // a character, or the interrupt will fire immediately.

    // Enable UART interrupts at the system level
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
}
```

If you need me to, I'll look into the HAL code and try and give you some more direct guidance, but I think it's valuable to take this, understand it, and translate it to your implementation.

Comment: see my answer below. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: when i add  " if(USART_SR_RXNE!=1){ " before  "uint8_t head_temp... " and if(USART_SR_TXE!=1){ " before "if (uart_tx_circBuff.head == uart_tx_circBuff.tail) " nothing has changed. Receive xxxxxxx and lot of strange characters.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a closer look at the HAL source code, and it looks like by using the `HAL_xxxx_IT()` functions, all the interrupt code is already handled for you. That said, there are a lot of similarities to doing it in bare metal in your application, since you're only sending and receiving one character at a time.

When you call `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_TXE)` you're telling the microcontroller to fire an interrupt when the data register is empty. But the HAL interrupt routine doesn't know what to transmit, so it'll send out garbage until it *thinks* it's finished.

I think another problem might be caused by directly accessing your circular buffer in multiple places, causing clashes. You'd be better off calling your HAL functions with a temporary buffer (or pointer to a single `char`) that either is taken from, or stores into, your circular buffer.

---

**Main function**

```
// Entry point
int main(void)
{
  // Initialise system and peripherals
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM10_Init();

  // Enable interrupts
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);

  // Prepare reception of the first character
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &received_char, 1);

  while (1)
  {
    char downloaded;
    if (UartReceiveChar(&downloaded) && downloaded == 'x')
      UartSendChar(downloaded);
  }
}
```

**UART wrapper**

```
// Function declarations
int8_t UartSendChar    (char  data);
void   UartSendString  (char* str);
int8_t UartReceiveChar (char* data);

// Variables
int8_t  isTransmitting = 0;
uint8_t sendingChar;
uint8_t receivedChar;


// Function definitions
// Callback function for when a character has finished sending by the HAL
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  // The HAL has just sent the tail byte from the TX buffer
  // If there is still data in the buffer, we want to send the
  // next byte in the buffer.
  if (buffer_pop_tx(&sendingChar))
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(huart, &sendingChar, 1);
  else
    isTransmitting = 0;
}

// Callback function for when a character is received by the HAL
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  // The HAL has received a character into 'receivedChar'
  // All we need to do is push it onto our circular buffer
  buffer_push_rx(receviedChar);
  // and prepare to receive the next character
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, &receivedChar, 1);
}

// Send a character
int8_t UartSendChar(char data)
{
  // Push the character onto the buffer
  int8_t returnValue = buffer_push_tx(data);

  // Start sending the buffer, if we're not already transmitting
  if (!isTransmitting)
  {
    sendingChar = data;
    isTransmitting = 1;
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, &sendingChar, 1);
  }

  return returnValue;
}

// Send a null-terminated string
int8_t UartSendString(char* str)
{
  // Iterate through all the non-null characters
  while (*str)
  {
    // Send the character; Wait if the buffer is full
    while (!UartSendChar(*str)) ;
    ++str;
  }
  return 1;
}

// Receive a character
int8_t UartReceiveChar(char* data)
{
  // Just a wrapper for buffer_pop_rx
  return buffer_pop_rx(data);
}
```

**Buffer implementation**

```
// I've changed your circular buffer size for optimisation purposes
#define UART_RX_BUF_SIZE 8
#define UART_TX_BUF_SIZE 8

// Buffer type definition
typedef struct
{
  volatile char *const buffer;
  uint8_t head;
  uint8_t tail;
  uint8_t isFull : 1;
  uint8_t isEmpty : 1;
  uint8_t hasOverflowed : 1;  // Overflow and underflow are only relevant if we choose to
  uint8_t hasUnderflowed : 1; // allow pushing and popping with an empty/full buffer
} circ_buffer_t;


// Function declarations
int8_t buffer_push_tx  (char  data);
int8_t buffer_push_rx  (char  data);
int8_t buffer_pop_tx   (char* data);
int8_t buffer_pop_rx   (char* data);


// Variables
volatile char uart_rxBuff[UART_RX_BUF_SIZE];
volatile char uart_txBuff[UART_TX_BUF_SIZE];
volatile circ_buffer_t uart_rx_circBuff = {uart_rxBuff, 0, 0};
volatile circ_buffer_t uart_tx_circBuff = {uart_txBuff, 0, 0};


// Function definitions
// Push a character onto the transmit buffer
int8_t buffer_push_tx(char data)
{
  if (uart_tx_circBuff.isFull) // buffer is full
  {
    // uart_tx_circBuff.hasOverflowed = 1; // Nasty things can happen if we allow overflows. But in some special cases, it may be necessary.
    return 0;
  }

  // Put the character at the head position and increment the head index
  uart_tx_circBuff.buffer[uart_tx_circBuff.head++] = data;
  uart_tx.circBuff.head &= (UART_TX_BUF_SIZE - 1); // don't use &= if the buffer size isn't a power of 2

  // mark the buffer as full if the head and tail indices are the same
  uart_tx_circBuff.isFull = (uart_tx_circBuff.head == uart_tx_circBuff.tail);
  uart_tx_circBuff.isEmpty = 0;

  // OK
  return 1;
}

// Push a character onto the receive buffer
int8_t buffer_push_rx(char data)
{
  if (uart_rx_circBuff.isFull) // buffer is full
  {
    // uart_rx_circBuff.hasOverflowed = 1;
    return 0;
  }

  // Put the character at the head position and increment the head index
  uart_rx_circBuff.buffer[uart_rx_circBuff.head++] = data;
  uart_rx.circBuff.head &= (UART_RX_BUF_SIZE - 1); // don't use &= if the buffer size isn't a power of 2

  // mark the buffer as full if the head and tail indices are the same
  uart_rx_circBuff.isFull = (uart_rx_circBuff.head == uart_rx_circBuff.tail);
  uart_rx_circBuff.isEmpty = 0;

  // OK
  return 1;
}

// Try to get a character from the receive buffer.
int8_t uart_pop_rx(char *data)
{
  if (uart_rx_circBuff.isEmpty) // buffer is empty
  {
    // uart_rx_circBuff.hasUnderflowed = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  
  // Put the character from the tail position of the buffer into 'data' and increment the tail index
  *data = uart_rx_circBuff.buffer[uart_rx_circBuff.tail++];
  uart_rx_circBuff.tail &= (UART_RX_BUF_SIZE - 1); // // don't use &= if the buffer size isn't a power of 2

  // mark the buffer as full if the head and tail indices are the same
  uart_rx_circBuff.isEmpty = (uart_rx_circBuff.head == uart_rx_circBuff.tail);
  uart_rx_circBuff.isFull = 0;

  // OK
  return 1;
}

// Try to get a character from the transmit buffer.
int8_t uart_pop_rx(char *data)
{
  if (uart_tx_circBuff.head == uart_tx_circBuff.tail) // buffer is empty
  {
    // uart_tx_circBuff.hasUnderflowed = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  
  // Put the character from the tail position of the buffer into 'data' and increment the tail index
  *data = uart_tx_circBuff.buffer[uart_tx_circBuff.tail++];
  uart_tx_circBuff.tail &= (UART_TX_BUF_SIZE - 1); // don't use &= if the buffer size isn't a power of 2

  // mark the buffer as full if the head and tail indices are the same
  uart_tx_circBuff.isEmpty = (uart_tx_circBuff.head == uart_tx_circBuff.tail);
  uart_tx_circBuff.isFull = 0;

  // OK
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I uploaded the code to the board, trying to understand why after sending a single character 'x' gets 'xx'. This works up to 7 times
I send x gets xx, when for the eighth time I send x I get infinite string 'xxxxxxxxxxx ...' which I have to terminate with a reset.
But when I send 7 characters at a time 'xxxxxxx'. is replaced by 8 characters 'xxxxxxxx'. After sending 8 'x' characters at a time, an infinite string that I have to interrupt with a reset.

Comment: How much of your original code are you still using? In your original post, you have `HAL_Uart_Transmit()` inside of your `RxCplt` callback, so that'll send back every character it receives. You also have `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_TXE)` inside of `uart_put_char`, so it'll start sending back undefined garbage whenever your put something in your TX buffer.

Comment: I have removed it. Now I am just analysing your code.